# Install an Android native library in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a question about the possibility to use an android native SDK library on React Native. I have read that I should create a "bridge" to do this.

Can anyone explain me pro and cons to use android native library on React Native? It's always possible? How can I do?

Thank you

Comment: You got first informations and examples [here, @ the documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android)

Comment: Obviusly I have read the documentation, only I would understand how can I apply for all library